# Getting error : Promise rejected with no or falsy reason in mocha selenium node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, mocha.js, chai

I am doing unit test with selenium mocha with node js, i am new in that, I want to test with rejection promise, but it is giving me this error : `Promise rejected with no or falsy reason`, can anyone please look my code and help me to resolve this issue, here i have pasted my whole code

```
it('Login', async function () {
    this.timeout(200000);
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
      driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox')
        .setFirefoxOptions(new firefox.Options().windowSize(screen))
        .build();
      driver.get('http://localhost:4200/login');
      await driver.findElement(By.id('mat-input-0')).sendKeys('root_admin');
      await driver.findElement(By.id('mat-input-1')).sendKeys('Admin123');
      await driver.sleep(5000);
      const button = await driver.findElement(By.className('mt-3'));
      await button.click();
      await driver.sleep(2000);
      await driver.quit();
      let text = "sdsdsds"
      if (text == "Invalid email or password") {
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are receiving this error message is that you are not putting any arguments into `reject()`.

If you change that to e.g. `reject(new Error('text does not match \"Invalid email or password\"'));` you should see that error message instead.

Comment: thanks for your help, you can upvote my question :)